# Angular - How perform page reloads with same url with :id that recieve from api post success

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ui-router

I am new to angular(v16).
How to achieve after submit post the data via api and return success with Id(Database id) and make the page navigate to same url page with /:id.
Also restore the data that i have saved into db initially after reload (Shall i fetch those data with id via api again and do patchValue) or is there better way to achieve for it?
Please assist on this. Thanks

Updated:

```
this.infoService.saveInfoNodeExcel(this.projectDto).subscribe({
        next: (response: any) => {
          if (response.status === "success") {
            this.spinner.hide();
            showSuccessModal();
            if(existsProjectId === null || existsProjectId === undefined){
              const newProjectId = response.data.Project.id ? response.data.Project.id : null;
              this.reloadCurrentRoute(newProjectId,true);
            }else{
              this.reloadCurrentRoute(existsProjectId,false);
            }
          }else{
            console.log(response.resp.description);
            showErrorModal();           
          }
        },
        error: (e) => console.error(e),
        complete: () => {
          this.cdr.detectChanges();
          this.spinner.hide();
        }
      });
```

reload method navigate to same page with route id

```
    reloadCurrentRoute(id:any,newRecord:boolean) {
    const currentUrl = (newRecord)? this.router.url+`/${id}` : this.router.url;
    this.router.navigateByUrl(`/`, { skipLocationChange: true }).then(() => {
      this.router.navigate([currentUrl]);
    });
  }
```

routing path

```
     { path: "workflow2", 
    component: Workflow2Component
  },
  { path: "workflow2/:id", 
    component: Workflow2Component,
    runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always'
  },
```

Routing Module

```
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true,  onSameUrlNavigation: 'reload'})],
```

exports: [RouterModule],

Comment: And what have you tried to achieve the routing? Please provide some code.

Comment: I have update above and that is what i have achieved so far. please advise.Thanks